# How to replace a backslash within quotes and without quotes?

Tags: python, string, replace

I have 3 strings :

```
 s='escape the backslash (\)' 
 t='escape the backslash ('\')' 
 u='escape the backslash ('\\')'
```

the results what i get while i print are:

```
1st case: escape the backslash (\\)
2nd case: escape the backslash ('')
3rd case: escape the backslash ('\\')
```

and now when i want to replace these backslashes `s.replace('\\','sp_dash_sp')` [similar with `t` and `u`]
then 1st case and 3rd case becomes : `escape the backslash(sp_dash_sp)`
and 2nd case becomes : `escape the backslash('')`

but my results I want it to be:

```
1st case:escape the backslash (sp_dash_sp)
2nd case:escape the backslash('sp_dash_sp')
3rd case: escape the backslash('sp_dash_spsp_dash_sp')
```

Please share your inputs.

Comment: can you manipulate the strings or just the way you do replace?

Comment: How do you print the data? If I do `print('escape the backslash (\)')` I get `escape the backslash (\)` (no double backslash).

Comment: your strings are incorrect - Python shows `Syntax error`

Answer (score 1):

Please try as below, insert your string into data.txt and run, I hope you'll get the desired output.
I've tried it with your strings which are mentioned in the question, it is working as expected.

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
     data = file.read()
     newda = data.replace('\\', "sp_dash_sp")
     print(newdata)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your strings should be raw to be able to escape two backslashes.

```
s=r'escape the backslash (\)' 
t=r"escape the backslash ('\') "
u=r"escape the backslash ('\\')"

print(s)
print(t)
print(u)
print(s.replace("\\","sp_dash_sp"))
print(t.replace("\\","sp_dash_sp"))
print(u.replace("\\","sp_dash_sp"))
```

This results in

```
escape the backslash (\)
escape the backslash ('\') 
escape the backslash ('\\')
escape the backslash (sp_dash_sp)
escape the backslash ('sp_dash_sp') 
escape the backslash ('sp_dash_spsp_dash_sp')
```

Is this helpful?

**Addition:** **Edit after the comment that the content is read from a file:**
Text file content:

```
escape the backslash (\)
escape the backslash ('\')
escape the backslash ('\\')
```

Python code to read and process the `\`:

```
with open('text_file.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read()
    print(data)
    print(data.replace("\\","sp_dash_sp"))
```

Result:

```
escape the backslash (\)
escape the backslash ('\')
escape the backslash ('\\')
escape the backslash (sp_dash_sp)
escape the backslash ('sp_dash_sp')
escape the backslash ('sp_dash_spsp_dash_sp')
```

Comment: Please add that what exactly is your file content and how are you reading the file. You must add all information required in your code.